# How to get back to the app manually after sending sms message

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, sms

After sending an SMS text message I receive SMS feedback. I copied it and I want to paste into applications. But I can not return to the application - the Cancel button turns to gray - inactive.

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {

    switch (result)
    {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Result: canceled");
             [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Result: sent");
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Result: failed");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Result: not sent");
            break;
    }

 //   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
-(void)sms{
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] ;
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        controller.body = @"message";
        controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"12344321", nil];
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: You need to phrase the question correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You need to uncomment `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`
This should work and will bring you back to your application by dismissing the `MFMessageComposeViewController` and based on your action `switch statement` in `- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result` will act accordingly.